# how can get span id from table data in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `table` `tr` and `td`. In between the table data there is a `span` that I want to take the ID from.

In my jquery code, it's not returning any value from `span` id.

How can get `span` id?

**My HTML**

```
<table border="1" id="t1">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span class="f1" id="111" onclick="subtract();">Subtract</span>
        </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>
            <span class="f2" id="222" onclick="subtract();">Subtract</span>
      </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**My jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#t1 span").click(function() {
        var a = $(this).id();
        alert(a);
    });
});
```

Comment: `$(this).attr('id')`

Comment: if i use inline onclick() on that time any problem created.

Comment: Learn to use your browser console to look at errors. You should see `id() is not a function` error but you never mentioned any errors. Those are major clues to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply pass the `this` in your `subtract` function:

```js
function subtract(element) {
    var a = element.id
    console.log(a);
}
```

```html
<table id="t1" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td><span id="111" class="f1" onclick="subtract(this);">Subtract</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><span id="222" class="f2" onclick="subtract(this);">Subtract</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Another solution is using jQuery [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

```js
$('table#t1 span').click(function() {
    var a = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log(a);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<table id="t1" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td><span id="111" class="f1">Subtract</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><span id="222" class="f2">Subtract</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 5):

Use jQuery's `attr` method:

```
var a = $(this).attr('id');
```

This allows you to take *any* attribute from any jQuery object element and return its value.

More info in the [jQuery attr() Docs](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `id` property of Element

```
var a = this.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

in jQuery, us the `attr` function to get attributed from HTML elements.  http://api.jquery.com/attr/

See working example using your code: https://jsfiddle.net/e2vonuor/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're chaining a non-existent method to a jQuery's `$(this)` object, `id` is neither a function nor a method, in either jQuery or DOM: it's a property, of an HTMLElement. So, instead use a valid jQuery method to retrieve the property:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#t1 span").click(function () {
        var a = $(this).prop('id');
        alert(a);
    });
});
```

Although you could, certainly, also use `attr()` in place of `prop()`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#t1 span").click(function () {
        var a = $(this).attr('id');
        alert(a);
    });
});
```

Or use the DOM:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#t1 span").click(function () {
        var a = this.id;
        alert(a);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You either use the inline "onclick" in which case you can send the actual element as a parameter:

```
<table id="t1" border="1">
<tr>
    <td><span id="111" class="f1" onclick="subtract(this);">Subtract</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><span id="222" class="f2" onclick="subtract(this);">Subtract</span></td>
</tr>
```

jQuery

```
function substract(spanElement){
   var id = $(spanElement).attr("id");
   alert(id);
}
```

Or you set the click functionality in the document ready:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#t1 span").click(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        alert(a);
    });
});
```

I also recommend you debug using console.log instead of the alert function. But this is a matter of preference.